# jQuery - if / else - change value of variable

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Let me first say I am a complete newb at jQuery, I am having a hard time fixing my current problem. I'm currently working on a project that uses the jQuery ScrollTo plugin. And I am trying to change the axis of the scrollTo function based on my current position on the webpage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $current_position = thuis;
var $axis = 'xy';

$('.box').stop().scrollTo(thuis, 0);

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.box').stop().scrollTo($current_position, 0);
}); 

// Scroll function
$('.toc a').click(function() {
    var $target = $(this.hash);
    if($current_position == bezoekers_info || liniepad_info){
        $axis = 'xy';
        alert("xy");
    } else {
        $axis = 'yx';
        alert("yx");
    }
    $('.box').stop().scrollTo($target, 1000, { queue:true, axis: $axis }, {easing: "easeInOutQuart"});
    $current_position = $target;
    return false;
});
});
```

The function basically works, but it will not change the axis value (it will stay at 'xy'). Whatever my position is, it will always alert me with "xy". Yet I know $current_position should work, because it does work in the window.resize function. If I change the $axis var at the top to 'yx' it will also work.

What am I missing here, obviously I am doing something wrong with my if / else statement?

Comment: Are you trying to say this in your if statement? `$current_position == bezoekers_info || $current_position == liniepad_info`otherwise it will always be true if `liniepad_info` is set.

Comment: I am actually. Basically, I want it to say:

If current position is either bezoekers_info or liniepad_info, return xy. If it is any of the other 3 possibilities, return yx.

I tried it with what you said, but now it constantly returns yx.

Comment: They way it is now, the if block will always run.

Answer (score 1):

add this to check your code...

```
alert($current_position + ', ' + bezoekers_info + ', ' + liniepad_info);
```

if those values are as expected, this should do the trick:

```
if( ($current_position == bezoekers_info) || ($current_position == liniepad_info) ){...
```

Comment: Still not working, the alert returns HTMLDivElement, while the new if statement always returns yx.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it using this:

```
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        if( (this.hash.substr(1) == "bezoekers_info") || (this.hash.substr(1) == "liniepad_info") ){
            $axis = 'yx';
        } else {
            $axis = 'xy'
        }
```

Apparently if you check the real text value of this.hash, you can get it to work. Not sure if it proper coding though, but at least it works for now.